# ReactPlayer subtitle not showing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, subtitle, react-player

I have a problem with **ReactPlayer** component. I'm trying to upload a subtitle(track) using config attribute and it isn't displayed onto the video.

I'm running this project on Chrome. In Networks I found out that my request was blocked with the error "blocked:origin" that's why I added:

```
attributes: {
    crossOrigin: 'true'
}
```

This is my **ReactPlayer** component:

```
<ReactPlayer
    url='video/myVideo'
    className="myClass"
    config= {
        file: {
            attributes: {
                crossOrigin: 'true'
            },
            tracks: [
                {kind: 'subtitles', src: 'subs/mySubtitle', srcLang: 'en', default: true}
            ]
        }
    }
/>
```

Also, I'm using React **v16.2.0** and ReactPlayer **v0.25.3**.

Comment: You might just be missing the .vtt `src: 'subs/mySubtitle.vtt'`

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

same question !

```
 tracks:        [
                            {
                                kind: 'subtitles',
                                src: this.state.trackUrl,
                                srcLang: 'en',
                                default: true,
                            },

                        ]
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever found a solution, but this worked for me (if you use absolute paths):

```
    import introVideoText from 'assets/impacti_intro.vtt';
```

then

```
    config={{
              file: {
                tracks: [
                  {
                    kind: 'subtitles',
                    src: introVideoText,
                    srcLang: 'en',
                    default: true,
                  }
                ],
              },
```